# How Control.VisibleChanged Event will be implemented

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to display runtime textbox control on the form .. & this action should be  performed when I click on the button BClick on the Form. When I click on the Button BClick, then textbox should be visible as mouse moves but the form with that textbox should not be visible . As I already used the Control. VisibleChanged Event but this is not working as my requirement expects.. please let me know related with this issue & How Control.VisibleChanged Event will be implemented in my example.

Comment: You haven't provided any code

Comment: then textbox should be visible as mouse moves but the form with that textbox should not be visible is not clear. Textbox is on other form?

Comment: @RajeevRanjan: Thanx for the giving your valuable time for my question. yes TextBox is on another form and button is on another form.. when I click on the button then with mouse move on the form the textbox should be visible without its form.

Comment: I think it is not possible if you are making a control visible then its container(form) will also visible.

Comment: @Rajeev:yes ,you are right.

Comment: You can't show your control but hide its parent (your form). unless you use some specific colors to distinguish your control with all the other parts on your form, then use the `TransparencyKey` to make all the other parts (except your control) totally transparent, of course it's applicable only if you set the `FormBorderStyle` to `None`, because the `TransparencyKey` can't hide the borders, it affects only the client region.

Comment: Another approach is use the `Region` property, you have to set the `Region` to the exact region covering the control on your form, that way your form will show only the control without any other parts.